# Encryption / Decryption String Indices Must Be Integers

Tags: python, arrays, encryption, integer

I have spent a lot of time creating this encryption program that is specific to an assignment. The encryption works perfectly, i thought i would be able to copy the code and do the opposite to decrypt the message, however i receive the error:

```
letter = encryptionCharacters[temp_k]
"TypeError: String indices must be integers"
```

Not sure if anyone can fix this issue to be able to decrypt a message, but hopefully someone can give me some help.

Steps to use the program:
Select option 1 by entering that number from the menu.
Enter 854417 as the number
Then press 2 and choose a message to encrypt / decrypt.

```py
from itertools import cycle

listOfDigits = []
listOfIllegalCharacters = []
encryptionCharacters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz .'
encryptedMessageLettersPosition = []
decryptedMessageLettersPosition =[]
encryptedMessageList = []

def main(): #This Function is the base of the main menu
    print()
    print("********* Welcome to the Encryption Program *********")
    print()

    while True: #Start of while loop to get the users choice.
        try: #Start of try method.
            choice = int(input("""
                                1: Set Person Number
                                2. Encrypt a Message
                                3. Decrypt a Message
                                4. Quit

                                Please Choose an Option (1 - 4): """)) #Interactive menu itself taking in the users option as an integer.
        except ValueError: #End of try method, in order to catch the possible value error of entering a string instead of an integer.
            print("!!!!!!ERROR!!!!!!")
            print()
            print("ERROR: Choice was not valid!")
            print("Try Again")
            print()
            print("!!!!!!ERROR!!!!!!")
            main() #Call to menu method (a.k.a restart).
        if choice == 1:
            personNumberInput() #Call to personNumberInput method, which allows the user to enter their personal ID number for the encryption.
        elif choice == 2:
            if len(listOfDigits) == 0:
                print()
                print("!!!!!!ERROR!!!!!!")
                print()
                print("You have not set a Person Number")
                print("Please Select Option 1 and set a Person Number to begin Encryption / Decryption")
                print()
                print("!!!!!!ERROR!!!!!!")
            else:
                messageEncrypt()
        elif choice == 3:
            if len(listOfDigits) == 0:
                print()
                print("!!!!!!ERROR!!!!!!")
                print()
                print("You have not set a Person Number")
                print("Please Select Option 1 and set a Person Number to begin Encryption / Decryption")
                print()
                print("!!!!!!ERROR!!!!!!")
            else:
                messageDecrypt() 
        elif choice == 4:
            menuQuit() 
        else:
            print()
            print("!!!!!!ERROR!!!!!!") #If none of the options are chosen, restart and provide a suitable error message.
            print()
            print("You must only select 1, 2, 3 or 4.")
            print("Please Try Again")
            print()
            print("!!!!!!ERROR!!!!!!")
            main()

def menuQuit(): #This function is the 4th option on the menu.
    print()
    userOption = input("Are you sure you want to Quit / Exit the Program? (Y/N): ") #Taking the users input to get their decision.
    if userOption == "y":
        exit() 
    elif userOption == "Y":
        exit() #Exit the program if the user confirms their choice with "y" or "Y".
    else:
        print()
        print("You have been returned to the Main Menu")
        main() #Returning the user to the menu for any other option including "n" or "N".

def personNumberInput():
    while True:
        try:
            print()
            personNumber = int(input("Please enter your Person Number: ")) #Checking the input from the user.
        except ValueError: #Catching the value error of unexpected value (non integer).
            print()
            print("ERROR: Person Number contained a non integer, Try Again") 
            continue
        else:
            personNumberInt = len(str(abs(personNumber))) #Getting the length of the string as well as the absolute value of each digit entered.
            break

    while True:    
        if (personNumberInt) != 6: #If the length of the number entered is not 6, try again.
            print()
            print("ERROR: Person Number length not equal to 6, Try Again")
            return personNumberInput()
        else:
            print()
            print ("The Person Number you have entered is:", personNumber)
            print ("Ready to Encrypt / Decrypt a Message")
            personNumberDigits = [int(x) for x in str(personNumber)]
            listOfDigits.extend(personNumberDigits)
            break

def messageEncrypt():
    print()
    message = input("Please Enter a Message to Encrypt: ")
    messageLetters = []
    messageLettersPosition = []

    for char in message:
        messageLetters += char


    for i in messageLetters:
        position = encryptionCharacters.find(i)
        position = position + 1
        messageLettersPosition.append(position)


    digits = messageLettersPosition
    values = cycle(listOfDigits)

    for j, (digit, value) in enumerate(zip(digits, values)):
        if j % 2 == 0: 
            val = digit - value-1
            encryptedMessageLettersPosition.append(val)
        elif j % 3 == 1:
            val = digit - value*3-1
            encryptedMessageLettersPosition.append(val)
        else:
            val = digit + value-1
            encryptedMessageLettersPosition.append(val)

    for k in encryptedMessageLettersPosition:
        temp_k = k % len(encryptionCharacters)
        letter = encryptionCharacters[temp_k]
        encryptedMessageList.append(letter)

    print()
    print ("Your message has been Encrypted!")
    print ("Encrypted Message Output:",(''.join(encryptedMessageList)))

encryptedMessageLettersPosition.clear()
encryptedMessageList.clear()

def messageDecrypt():
    print()
    message = input("Please Enter a Message to Decrypt: ")
    messageLetters = []
    messageLettersPosition = []

    for char in message:
        messageLetters += char

    for i in messageLetters:
        position = encryptionCharacters.find(i)
        position = position + 1
        messageLettersPosition.append(position)

    digits = messageLettersPosition
    values = cycle(listOfDigits)

    for j, (digit, value) in enumerate(zip(digits, values)):
        if j % 2 == 0: 
            val = digit + value-1
            encryptedMessageLettersPosition.append(val)
        elif j % 3 == 1:
            val = digit + value/3-1
            encryptedMessageLettersPosition.append(val)
        else:
            val = digit - value-1
            encryptedMessageLettersPosition.append(val)

    for k in encryptedMessageLettersPosition:
        temp_k = k % len(encryptionCharacters)
        letter = encryptionCharacters[temp_k]
        encryptedMessageList.append(letter)

main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try making temp_k an integer using int()

```
 temp_k = int( k % len(encryptionCharacters) )
 letter = encryptionCharacters[temp_k]
```

Comment: np,  happy to help

Answer (score 0):

Some of the values in `encryptedMessageLettersPosition` are floats, not integers.

Therefore `temp_k = k % len(encryptionCharacters)` sometimes returns a float value, and you cannot use a float as a string index.